При скроллинге на мобильном не расширяется сайт
https://m.taraz.zeta.kz/ При скроллинге на мобильном сайт не разворачивается полностью. Помогите понять в чём проблема.
{{ header }}
<link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>

<script src="catalog/view/javascript/modal.js"></script>


{#
****************** 
* @package SO Framework for Opencart 3.x
* @author  http://www.opencartworks.com
* @license GNU General Public License
* @copyright(C) 2008-2017 opencartworks.com. All rights reserved.
******************
#}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir="{{ direction }}" lang="ru">
<head>
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >



<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<base href="{{ base }}" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0"> 
{% if description %}<meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />{% endif %}
{% if keywords %}<meta name="keywords" content="{{ keywords }}" />{% endif %}
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->

{# =========== Begin General CSS ==============#}
{% if direction=='ltr' %} {{soconfig.addCss('catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}
{% elseif direction=='rtl' %}{{soconfig.addCss('catalog/view/javascript/soconfig/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.rtl.min.css')}} 
{% else %}{{soconfig.addCss('catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}} {% endif %}

{{soconfig.addCss('catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}
{{soconfig.addCss('catalog/view/javascript/icomoon/style.min.css')}}
{{soconfig.addCss('catalog/view/javascript/soconfig/css/lib.css')}}

{% if direction=='rtl' %}{{soconfig.addCss('catalog/view/javascript/soconfig/css/ratchet/ratchet-rtl.css')}} 
{% else %}{{soconfig.addCss('catalog/view/javascript/soconfig/css/ratchet/ratchet.css')}} {% endif %}

{% for style in styles %}{{ soconfig.addCss(style.href)}}{% endfor %}

{# =========== Begin General Scripts ==============#}
{{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')}}
{{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}
{{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/javascript/soconfig/js/libs.js')}}
{{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/javascript/lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js')}}

{% if soconfig.get_settings('barnav') %}
 {{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/javascript/soconfig/js/mobile/topnav.js')}}
{% endif %} 
{{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/javascript/soconfig/js/mobile/so.mobile.js')}}
{{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/javascript/soconfig/js/ratchet/ratchet.js')}}


{{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/theme/'theme_directory'/js/so.custom.js')}}
{{soconfig.addJs('catalog/view/theme/'theme_directory'/js/common.js')}}
{% for script in scripts %} {{soconfig.addJs(script)}} {% endfor %}


{# =========== Begin Other CSS & JS  ==============#}
{{soconfig.scss_compassMobile}}
{{soconfig.css_out(soconfig.get_settings('cssExclude'))}}
{{soconfig.js_out(soconfig.get_settings('jsExclude'))}}


{# =========== Begin Google Font ==============#}
{% if soconfig.get_settings('murl_body')  and  soconfig.get_settings('mbody_status') ==  'google' %} <link href='{{ soconfig.get_settings('murl_body') }}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> {% endif %}    
{% if soconfig.get_settings('murl_heading')  and  soconfig.get_settings('mheading_status') ==  'google' %} <link href='{{ soconfig.get_settings('murl_heading') }}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> {% endif %}   
{% if mselector_body %}
 <style type="text/css">
     {% if soconfig.get_settings('mbody_status') == 'google' %} {{ (mselector_body~'{font-family:'~ soconfig.get_settings('mfamily_body')~'}') }}
     {% else %}  {{ mselector_body~'{font-family:'~ soconfig.get_settings('mnormal_body')~'}' }}{% endif %} 
 </style>
{% endif %} 


{% if mselector_heading %}
 <style type="text/css">
     {% if soconfig.get_settings('mheading_status') == 'google' %} {{ (mselector_heading~'{font-family:'~ soconfig.get_settings('mfamily_heading')~'}') }}
     {% else %}  {{ mselector_heading~'{font-family:'~ soconfig.get_settings('mnormal_heading')~'}' }}{% endif %} 
 </style>
{% endif %} 



{# =========== Begin Google Analytics ==============#}
{% for link in links %}<link href="{{ link.href }}" rel="{{ link.rel }}" />{% endfor %}
 {% for analytic in analytics %}
 {{ analytic }}
{% endfor %}


</head>

{# =========== Add class Body ==============#}
{% set cls_body = class ~ ' ' %}
{% set cls_body = cls_body ~ direction %}
{% set cls_body = cls_body ~ ' mobilelayout-'~soconfig.get_settings('mobilelayout')%}
 
<body class="{{cls_body}}">
{% include theme_directory~'/template/soconfig/panel_left.twig' %}

<div id="wrapper">  
{# =========== Show Panel Bar==============#}
{% if soconfig.get_settings('bottombar_status') %}
 {% include theme_directory~'/template/soconfig/panel_bar.twig' with {typeheader: soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader')} %}
{% endif %}
{# =========== Show Header==============#}
{% if soconfig.get_settings('barnav') %}
 {% if soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader') =='1'%}
     {% include theme_directory~'/template/header/header1.twig' with {typeheader: soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader')} %}
 {% elseif soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader') =='2'%}
     {% include theme_directory~'/template/header/header2.twig' with {typeheader: soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader')} %}
 {% elseif soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader') == '3' %}
     {% include theme_directory~'/template/header/header3.twig' with {typeheader: soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader')} %}
 {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<!-- Begin Main Content -->
<div class="content">

{# =========== Show Header==============#}
{% if soconfig.get_settings('barnav') == 0 %}
 {% if soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader') =='1'%}
     {% include theme_directory~'/template/header/header1.twig' with {typeheader: soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader')} %}
 {% elseif soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader') =='2'%}
     {% include theme_directory~'/template/header/header2.twig' with {typeheader: soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader')} %}
 {% elseif soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader') == '3' %}
     {% include theme_directory~'/template/header/header3.twig' with {typeheader: soconfig.get_settings('mtypeheader')} %}
 {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<style>
html {
translate ="no"
}
</style>

<script>
// catalog/view/javascript/modal.js
document.getElementById("openModalBtn").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("modalWindow").style.display = "block";
};

document.getElementById("closeModalBtn").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("modalWindow").style.display = "none";
};

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == document.getElementById("modalWindow")) {
 document.getElementById("modalWindow").style.display = "none";
}
};
</script>

<style>
.fullscreen {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 9999; /* Установите высокий z-index, чтобы элемент был поверх других */
}
</style>


как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

снегом замело ‍ (у вас на сайте идет снееееег☃️❄️) // приведите код здесь, основной страницы

Добавил код страницы


почему у вас viewport дважды указан 2. это все css ? почему то нету html, body {
height: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}.content {
min-height: 100vh; /* берет всю высоту*/
} 2.2. что такое translate ="no" (это не имеет отношения к высоте, просто вопрос от меня) 3. а дальше профи подскажут, потому что я не знаю .fullscreen z-index: 9999 может сломать высоту или как


Я больше скажу, сайт на мобильном у меня не грузится вообще ваш. А в Браузере на компьютере грузится и прокручивается до Футера нормально

@ЕвгенийЛи, да, точно проверила не открывается пишет, переадресация была сделана много раз.....а до этого я проверяла в тулс (версия самсунг симмуляция хром), и там увидела, что не прокручивается, просто застревает и дергается
